# Chained select boxes with jquery/php/database not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, chained

It seems that most chained selects are accomplished with JSON, but unfortunately it's much more convenient for me to use my database to accomplish this.  It's almost there, but for some reason the second select box is not loading up properly.  Instead it's loading the entire HTML for the page that it's on and I'm not sure why.

Here's what I've got (note that make_list() and model_list() are functions I previously built that return an array appropriate to their respective criteria)

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $("select#category").change(function(){
        $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#type").html("<option>loading...</option>");
        var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
            $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#type").html(data);
        });
    });
    $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
        var cat = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
        var type = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
        if(cat>0 && type>0)
        {
            var result = $("select#type option:selected").html();
            $("#result").html('your choice: '+result);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

The HTML/PHP:

```
<form id="select_form">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <select id="category">
        <option value="">Any</option>
        <?php foreach ( make_list() as $make ) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $make ?>"><?php echo $make ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <select id="type">
        <option value="">Any</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

When the first select is changed JQuery should look at a file in the same folder called 'select_type.php'.  Here's what's in that file (strangely $_POST['id'] doesn't seem to be appending to this file either, despite it being created in the JS):

```
foreach ( model_list($_POST['id']) as $model ) {
    echo '<option value="'.$model.'">'.$model.'</option>';
}
```

I've been using this resource for this project: http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-to-create-chained-select-with-php-and-jquery/ and it's gotten me most of the way, but unfortunately the data doesn't seem to be loading into that second select box.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured this one out.  Hopefully this helps someone with the same problem in the future.

The call to the file, select_type.php was incorrect.  The call must be absolute rather than relative.  Since I'm using wordpress I simply changed the line to this:

```
$.get("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/select-model.php'; ?>", {id:id}, function(data){
```

You'll notice that I changed $.post to $.get.  I'm not sure why post wasn't working, but get seems to work fine.  I'm just retrieving my values in select_type.php using $_GET['id'].

Hope this helps someone!